# how to create correct and specific json in a servlet in java

Tags: java, json, servlets

i need to return a json,  example

```
"employees": [
    {"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe"}, 
    {"firstName": "Anna", "lastName": "Smith"}, 
    {"firstName": "Peter", "lastName": "Jones"}
]
```

this is my code but i cant get the result

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
            ArrayList tipopropiedades = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = 0; i < tp.length; i++) {
                JSONObject detalle = new JSONObject();
                TipoPropiedadTO ti = tp[i];
                System.out.println(ti.getIdTipoCompra()+"  "+ti.getNombreTipoCompra());
                detalle.put("nombre",ti.getNombreTipoCompra().trim());
                array.add(detalle);
            }
```

the result of code when i get the alert(data) is

```
[{"nombre":"Casa"}, {"nombre":"Departamento"}, {"nombre":"Oficina"}, {"nombre":"Sitio Habitacional"}, {"nombre":"Sitio Comercial"}, {"nombre":"Sitio Industrial"}, {"nombre":"Agricola"}, {"nombre":"Parcela"}, {"nombre":"Bodega"}, {"nombre":"Estacionamiento"}]
```

Comment: Hi, if what you need is a list of employees..cant you have Employee class and serialize a list of that instead of building the object like you do now. With gson like this for example: https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html

Answer (score 0):

What you need to return is a JSONObject containing that JSONArray as a field called "employees".

And you need to translate the fields in the objects you put into that JSONArray to have the proper names.